# How to make adding product mandatory while creating an opportunity and opportunity stage is won

Tags: validation

I want to make adding product mandatory while creating an opportunity and when the opportunity stage is won.
I have written on validation rule but it is allowing user to save the opportunity by clicking on cancel button on add product.

```
AND 
( 
OR( 
ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Opp Won"), 
ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Fabricator Awarded") 
), 
Total_Opp_Quantity__c <= 0, 
HasOpportunityLineItem = FALSE, 
NOT(ISNEW()) 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't literally make products required on create, because then you'd have a Catch-22 situation. You would not be able to save the record without adding products, but you cannot create products for a record that does not yet exist. I would suggest two validation rules. The first prohibits creating a closed/won opportunity on create, the second prohibits closing without products.

---

```
AND( ISNEW(), IsWon )
```

---

```
AND( IsWon, NOT( HasOpportunityLineItem ))
```

Comment: Sometimes i just read your answers to find such terms : Catch-22 -> a problematic situation for which the only solution is denied by a circumstance inherent in the problem or by a rule. Awesome one word.